# Typescript update

Tags: typescript, gulp

I want to make sure I have updated my project to the latest version of Typescript. The command I have ran was this `npm install -g typescript@latest`. Also when I run `tsc -v` that will return Version 4.6.4. I there anything more I need to do in the `tsconfig.json` or the `gulpfile.js` to be sure this is getting compile with the latest version? Or anything in Visual Studio I need to install?

When I run `ng version` I see 1.8.10

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.1
Node: 16.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 2.2.4
... common, compiler, core, forms, http, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, upgrade

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.1
@angular/cli                 6.2.1
@angular/router              3.2.4
@schematics/angular          0.8.1
@schematics/update           0.8.1
rxjs                         5.0.0-beta.12
typescript                   1.8.10
```

But when I run `tsc -v` I see 4.6.4

```
Version 4.6.4
```

Comment: Update the dev dependency versions?

Comment: so this line the in the package.json "typescript": "^1.8.10",?

Comment: Running `npm install -g <package>` installs the package globally, it doesn't update anything defined in your project package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g typescript@latest` means you install the package globally in Node.js folder (not in your project folder)

As [the document](https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages)

> global packages are all put in a single place in your system (exactly where depends on your setup), regardless of where you run npm install -g

For adding that package to your project as a dependency, we have 2 approaches

**The first approach**

Modifying the expected package version specifically in `package.json`. In your case, it would be `"typescript": "^4.6.4"` (it will be compatible from version 4.6.4 to 5.0.0)

```
"dependencies": {
   "typescript": "^4.6.4"
},
```

And then running

```
npm install
```

Or

```
yarn install
```

(these commands to help you update local packages in your project)

This approach is preferable because of package stabilization. If you always try to install the latest package without proper testing for compatibility, your current application may be crashed

**The second approach**

You need to go to your project folder in your terminal by commands (like `cd`)

*Note that you need to be at the root level of your project folder which has `package.json`*

And then you can use this

```
npm install --save-exact typescript@latest
```

If you consider using `yarn`, you can follow this command

```
yarn add typescript@latest --exact
```

You check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-meaning-of-save-for-npm-install/) to understand more about other `npm install` commands with options